# Testing First-Order Stochastic Dominance Using R

Tags: r, cdf

I ran simulation and generated two (random) variables: X and Y.

I would like to test whether X first-order stochastically dominates Y in R.

That is, how can I check whether X's empirical CDF is on the right side of Y's empirical CDF for all support?

Comment: can you share code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: As of now, I simply plot the cdf and use ecdf function and inspect this visually..